# Navigation drawer + ViewPager - fragments do not show

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-navigation

I have a problem with the layout I created. I used the Navigation Drawer as a main navigation pattern. It looks and works as I wanted, but the problem is that after returning to the fragment which holds `ViewPager` - the inner-fragments are not shown. However, they are shown when the application is first opened and shows the `ViewPager`-holding `Fragment` by default.

Other navigation drawer `Fragments` are displayed ok, so I don't expect that there is any problem with my Navigation Drawer implementation

RecordFragment.java (fragment holding `ViewPager` `Fragments`):

```
public class RecordFragment extends Fragment {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public RecordFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_fragment, container, false);
        //getActivity().setTitle(R.string.record);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.record_pager);
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(manager));
    }

    class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int item) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (item == 0) {

                fragment = new NumbersFragment();
            } else if (item == 1) {

                fragment = new MapFragment();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = new String();
            if (position == 0) {
                title = "Numbers";
            } else if (position == 1) {
                title = "Map";
            }
            return title;
        }

    }
}
```

NumbersFragment.java (one of the `Fragments` holded by `RecordFragment`)

```
public class NumbersFragment extends Fragment {
    public NumbersFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.numbers_fragment, container, false);
        //getActivity().setTitle(R.string.record);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

record_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/record_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `Fragment`s inside another `Fragment`, in this case you need to use the [Fragment#getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) method:

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
```

If it doesn't work you can try to switch to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` (but you still need to use child fragment manager).

Comment: +100 up votes if I could.  This saved me from a different issue where my fragments weren't showing up with a VerticalViewPager nested inside of a Horizontal View Pager.  This line of code saved my work sprint!

Answer (score -1):

As the ViewPager required Fragments and ViewPager itself on Fragment, we have to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.